# Why is cofinite topology on a countable set a second countable space?

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

Consider a countable set $X$ with cofinite topology. [Here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000015/properties/P000027) the claim is that $X$ is second countable.

The simple argument is as follows :

$\color{red}{\text{Since $X$ is countable, the number of finite sets in $X$ are countable.}}$ Hence the number of open sets in $X$ are also countable. Since the topology itself is countable, the space is second countable.

> **Question: Why should it be true that the number of finite subsets of a countable set is countable?**

Comment: Enumerate the set $1,2,3,...$ and map each finite subset $A$ to $\sum_{n\in A}2^{n}$. This map is an injection into $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @logarithm What set are you enumerating? And by enumerating it, you already assume that it is countable.

Comment: @MarkKamsma The only set around that is given countable.

Comment: He's enumerating your set $X$. And you have assumed that $X$ is countable.

Comment: @logarithm Ah yes, I read too quickly